# Can I acquire an Element of Dawn without losing the Memento Mori?

Tags: sunless-sea

The [Memento Mori](http://sunlesssea.gamepedia.com/Memento_Mori) seems like the best forward weapon, not only because of its damage but because it grants a nice bonus to captain stats. I am trying to construct the The [Fulgent Impeller](http://sunlesssea.gamepedia.com/The_Fulgent_Impeller) so I can upgrade to a larger ship and still move around at a fast and fuel-efficient pace.

However, one component required to construct the Fulgent Impeller is an [Element of Dawn](http://sunlesssea.gamepedia.com/Element_of_Dawn), and the wiki lists only one way to acquire one: trade the Memento Mori for it at the Grand Geode. Is there some other way to get an Element of Dawn that won't require me to lose the weapon I just spend several hours constructing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Edit: Updated as of 18th Feb.

1) You can pass your Memento Mori to an heir, who will then have potentially 2.

2) As of 17th Feb, you can buy an element of dawn directly for about 1500 echoes worth of stuff (50 supplies, 7 crew, 1 Vital Intelligence) in the Grand Geode.

Comment: buy supplies in Naples, the price gets roughly cut in half.